# How to get code coverage of functional tests written in selenium python for a browser extension?

Tags: node.js, python-3.x, selenium, browser-automation, istanbul

I have prepared a browser extension which is written in NodeJS. I have UTs for all of the files in my source code but I wanted to write Test Cases in Python Selenium for Functional Testing. I have all the Test Cases ready but I am not sure how much of my code is being hit by the Test Cases. I am trying to find a way to get the code coverage. I tried using Istanbul and tried instrumenting the code and then building the extension with the instrumented code. Now when I install this extension with the instrumented code, I am not able to get the coverage after my Test Case is executed. I used this as a reference which I found to be very helpful:
https://medium.com/@the1mills/front-end-javascript-test-coverage-with-istanbul-selenium-4b2be44e3e98

I just need some abstraction about the same, I'll do the digging myself, just some help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Got the answer, we need to first instrument the file for which we want to know the code coverage(check the link in the question for reference). Once the file is instrumented then we need to build the browser extension with this instrumented code instead of the actual code. After loading the extension in the browser run the Functional Tests and in the end of the all the Functional Tests run the following command in the browser console:

```
window.__coverage__
```

This command will return the code coverage information for the file in form of a dictionary. The information can be written in form of a JSON and then visualised using istanbul's report command like this:

```
istanbul report --include path/to/my-coverage-file.json --dir my-coverage-dir html
```

This command will generate report in form of html.